# Updates: Mavericks 10.9.2 + Critical Security Update → no reboot

Tags: macos, security, software-update, reboot

### Update

On an iMac running Mavericks 10.9.0,

I just selected within App Store the 2 last OS updates:

- Critical Security Update (version 1.0)
- OS X Update Combined (version 10.9.2)

These 2 updates took "some" time, and terminated on a small square window
telling me something like "Installing items" (I didn't take a snap shot
since I didn't suspect these updates to be dangerous).

### Black hole

At `08:15`, my iMac shut down, but let me with a black screen (this a small
extract of `/var/log/system.log`<sup>1</sup>):

```
Mar 25 08:15:36 my_iMAC.my_domain reboot[18899]: SHUTDOWN_TIME: 1395731736 233985
Mar 25 08:15:36 my_iMAC.my_domain WindowServer[18760]: CGXGetConnectionProperty: Invalid connection 31491
Mar 25 08:33:02 localhost bootlog[0]: BOOT_TIME 1395732782 0
```

After 15 minutes of blackness, I decided this is enough of secrecy about a
serious problem, and decided to see if something was alive:

- no network access
- no reply to the sound level keyboard

Clearly the system is either completely dead or shutdown.

At 08:33 I used the power button, and the system booted up normally.

The system was upgraded "apparently" correctly (the apparently is here because I can't trust this system anymore):
[image]

Here is the App Store status after the "black hole" experience:
[image]

From my point of vue this a very serious bug:
on any upgrade a any system must come back on a running and thoroughly checked state.

---

### Analysis

How may I investigate this upgrade misbehaviour?

How may I identify if it is due to:

- the original state of my iMac which wasn't clean enough to be
  proposed these 2 updates,
- the Critical Security Updates,
- the OS X Update Combined?

---

<sup>1</sup>)  Here is a larger extract of `/var/log/system.log`:

```
Mar 25 08:08:44 MY_MAC_FQDN ReceiptInstaller[18712]: ReceiptDispatch: Set auto update preference to 0
Mar 25 08:08:57 --- last message repeated 1 time ---
Mar 25 08:08:57 MY_MAC_FQDN sfnctl[18738]: Notifying
Mar 25 08:08:57 MY_MAC_FQDN sfnctl[18738]: Message sent, terminating.
Mar 25 08:09:02 MY_MAC_FQDN com.apple.WebKit.WebContent[18705]: ERROR: ITSExceptionHandler: {message:"TypeError: 'null' is not an object (evaluating 'document.querySelector("#header").addClassName')", url:"https://se.itunes.apple.com/htmlResources/CAF7/da-storefront-autoinstallations.js", lineNumber:"326"}
Mar 25 08:09:04 MY_MAC_FQDN SSLFixNotifier[18739]: FNAppDelegate: Non-interactive authorization succeeded for non-admin user
Mar 25 08:09:04 MY_MAC_FQDN SSLFixNotifier[18739]: FNAppDelegate: authorizing PKInstallClient and SUAppStoreUpdateController
Mar 25 08:09:05 MY_MAC_FQDN Dock[169]: LaunchPad: __53-[LPAppManager(StoreSupport) _acceptStoreConnection:]_block_invoke app store xpc message error: Connection invalid
Mar 25 08:09:05 MY_MAC com.apple.launchd.peruser.501[152] ([0x0-0x5005].org.macosforge.xquartz.X11[166]): Exited: Killed: 9
Mar 25 08:09:05 MY_MAC com.apple.launchd.peruser.501[152] ([0x0-0x4004].com.apple.systempreferences[164]): Exited: Killed: 9
Mar 25 08:09:05 MY_MAC_FQDN WindowServer[98]: CGXGetConnectionProperty: Invalid connection 51719
Mar 25 08:09:05 --- last message repeated 16 times ---
Mar 25 08:09:05 MY_MAC com.apple.launchd[1] (com.apple.ShareKitHelper[200]): Exited: Killed: 9
Mar 25 08:09:05 MY_MAC com.apple.launchd.peruser.501[152] (com.apple.lateragent[14417]): Exited: Killed: 9
Mar 25 08:09:05 MY_MAC com.apple.launchd.peruser.501[152] (com.apple.SSLFixNotifier.agent[18739]): Exited: Killed: 9
Mar 25 08:09:05 MY_MAC com.apple.launchd.peruser.501[152] (com.apple.EscrowSecurityAlert[312]): Exited: Killed: 9
Mar 25 08:09:05 MY_MAC com.apple.launchd.peruser.501[152] (com.apple.AirPlayUIAgent[202]): Exited: Killed: 9
Mar 25 08:09:05 MY_MAC com.apple.launchd.peruser.501[152] (com.apple.talagent[18743]): Exited: Killed: 9
Mar 25 08:09:05 MY_MAC_FQDN UserEventAgent[11]: Captive: [UserAgentDied:142] User Agent @port=66823 Died
Mar 25 08:09:05 MY_MAC com.apple.launchd.peruser.501[152] (com.apple.UserEventAgent-Aqua[155]): Exited: Killed: 9
Mar 25 08:09:06 MY_MAC_FQDN sessionlogoutd[18755]: sessionlogoutd Launched
Mar 25 08:09:06 MY_MAC_FQDN sessionlogoutd[18755]: DEAD_PROCESS: 57 console
Mar 25 08:09:07 MY_MAC_FQDN loginwindow[57]: ERROR | SLODErrorHandler | Connection to sessionlogoutd lost, exiting loginwindow
Mar 25 08:09:07 MY_MAC_FQDN WindowServer[98]: CGXRestartSessionWorkspace: session workspace exited for session 256 (on console)
Mar 25 08:09:07 MY_MAC_FQDN WindowServer[98]: Session 256 released (1 references)
Mar 25 08:09:07 MY_MAC_FQDN WindowServer[98]: Session 256 released (0 references)
Mar 25 08:09:07 MY_MAC_FQDN WindowServer[98]: loginwindow connection closed; closing server.
Mar 25 08:09:07 MY_MAC_FQDN identityservicesd[206]: Quit - notifying about shutdown
Mar 25 08:09:07 MY_MAC_FQDN identityservicesd[206]: Quit - shutting down daemon
Mar 25 08:09:07 MY_MAC_FQDN imagent[201]: Quit - notifying about shutdown
Mar 25 08:09:07 MY_MAC_FQDN imagent[201]: Quit - shutting down daemon
Mar 25 08:09:07 MY_MAC com.apple.launchd[1] (com.apple.loginwindow[57]): Exited with code: 3
Mar 25 08:09:07 MY_MAC_FQDN ubd[183]: CGSLookupServerRootPort: Failed to look up the port for "com.apple.windowserver.active" (1102)
Mar 25 08:09:07 --- last message repeated 5 times ---
Mar 25 08:09:07 MY_MAC_FQDN loginwindow[18759]: Login Window Application Started
Mar 25 08:09:07 MY_MAC_FQDN WindowServer[18760]: Server is starting up
Mar 25 08:09:07 MY_MAC_FQDN WindowServer[18760]: Session 256 retained (2 references)
Mar 25 08:09:07 MY_MAC_FQDN WindowServer[18760]: Session 256 released (1 references)
Mar 25 08:09:07 MY_MAC_FQDN WindowServer[18760]: Session 256 retained (2 references)
Mar 25 08:09:07 MY_MAC_FQDN WindowServer[18760]: init_page_flip: page flip mode is on
Mar 25 08:09:07 MY_MAC_FQDN WindowServer[18760]: Found 30 modes for display 0x00000000 [27, 3]
Mar 25 08:09:07 MY_MAC_FQDN WindowServer[18760]: Found 1 modes for display 0x00000000 [1, 0]
Mar 25 08:09:07 MY_MAC_FQDN WindowServer[18760]: mux_initialize: Couldn't find any matches
Mar 25 08:09:07 MY_MAC_FQDN WindowServer[18760]: Found 30 modes for display 0x00000000 [27, 3]
Mar 25 08:09:07 MY_MAC_FQDN WindowServer[18760]: Found 1 modes for display 0x00000000 [1, 0]
Mar 25 08:09:07 MY_MAC_FQDN WindowServer[18760]: WSMachineUsesNewStyleMirroring: false
Mar 25 08:09:07 MY_MAC_FQDN WindowServer[18760]: Display 0x04273780: GL mask 0x1; bounds (0, 0)[1920 x 1080], 30 modes available
    Main, Active, on-line, enabled, built-in, boot, Vendor 610, Model 9cde, S/N 0, Unit 0, Rotation 0
    UUID 0x664eb65e435ae94400aecfc5ee1aeecc
Mar 25 08:09:07 MY_MAC_FQDN WindowServer[18760]: Display 0x003f003d: GL mask 0x2; bounds (0, 0)[0 x 0], 1 modes available
    off-line, enabled, Vendor ffffffff, Model ffffffff, S/N ffffffff, Unit 1, Rotation 0
    UUID 0xffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff
Mar 25 08:09:07 MY_MAC_FQDN WindowServer[18760]: WSSetWindowTransform: Singular matrix
Mar 25 08:09:07 MY_MAC_FQDN WindowServer[18760]: Display 0x04273780: GL mask 0x1; bounds (0, 0)[1920 x 1080], 30 modes available
    Main, Active, on-line, enabled, built-in, boot, Vendor 610, Model 9cde, S/N 0, Unit 0, Rotation 0
    UUID 0x664eb65e435ae94400aecfc5ee1aeecc
Mar 25 08:09:07 MY_MAC_FQDN WindowServer[18760]: Display 0x003f003d: GL mask 0x2; bounds (2944, 0)[1 x 1], 1 modes available
    off-line, enabled, Vendor ffffffff, Model ffffffff, S/N ffffffff, Unit 1, Rotation 0
    UUID 0xffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff
Mar 25 08:09:07 MY_MAC_FQDN WindowServer[18760]: CGXPerformInitialDisplayConfiguration
Mar 25 08:09:07 MY_MAC_FQDN WindowServer[18760]:   Display 0x04273780: Unit 0; Vendor 0x610 Model 0x9cde S/N 0 Dimensions 18.70 x 10.51; online enabled built-in, Bounds (0,0)[1920 x 1080], Rotation 0, Resolution 1
Mar 25 08:09:07 MY_MAC_FQDN WindowServer[18760]:   Display 0x003f003d: Unit 1; Vendor 0xffffffff Model 0xffffffff S/N -1 Dimensions 0.00 x 0.00; offline enabled, Bounds (2944,0)[1 x 1], Rotation 0, Resolution 1
Mar 25 08:09:07 MY_MAC_FQDN WindowServer[18760]: GLCompositor: GL renderer id 0x01021a08, GL mask 0x00000003, accelerator 0x00003d93, unit 0, caps QEX|MIPMAP, vram 256 MB
Mar 25 08:09:07 MY_MAC_FQDN WindowServer[18760]: GLCompositor: GL renderer id 0x01021a08, GL mask 0x00000003, texture max 8192, viewport max {8192, 8192}, extensions FPRG|NPOT|GLSL|FLOAT
Mar 25 08:09:07 MY_MAC_FQDN WindowServer[18760]: GLCompositor enabled for tile size [256 x 256]
Mar 25 08:09:07 MY_MAC_FQDN WindowServer[18760]: CGXGLInitMipMap: mip map mode is on
Mar 25 08:09:07 MY_MAC_FQDN loginwindow[18759]: **DMPROXY** Found `/System/Library/CoreServices/DMProxy'.
Mar 25 08:09:08 MY_MAC_FQDN sandboxd[272] ([183]): ubd(183) deny file-read-data /Users/dan/Library/Cookies/Cookies.binarycookies
Mar 25 08:09:08 MY_MAC_FQDN WindowServer[18760]: Display 0x04273780: Unit 0; ColorProfile { 2, "iMac"}; TransferTable (256, 3)
Mar 25 08:09:08 MY_MAC_FQDN launchctl[18762]: com.apple.findmymacmessenger: Already loaded
Mar 25 08:09:08 MY_MAC_FQDN loginwindow[18759]: USER_PROCESS: 18759 console
Mar 25 08:09:08 MY_MAC_FQDN com.apple.SecurityServer[14]: Session 100020 created
Mar 25 08:09:09 MY_MAC_FQDN UserEventAgent[18767]: Failed to copy info dictionary for bundle /System/Library/UserEventPlugins/alfUIplugin.plugin
Mar 25 08:09:09 MY_MAC_FQDN WindowServer[18760]: **DMPROXY** (2) Found `/System/Library/CoreServices/DMProxy'.
Mar 25 08:09:09 MY_MAC_FQDN WindowServer[18760]: Display 0x04273780: Unit 0; ColorProfile { 2, "iMac"}; TransferTable (256, 3)
Mar 25 08:09:10 --- last message repeated 1 time ---
Mar 25 08:09:10 MY_MAC_FQDN WindowServer[18760]: _CGXGLDisplayContextForDisplayDevice: acquired display context (0x7f9e48c1b3d0) - enabling OpenGL
Mar 25 08:09:41 MY_MAC_FQDN mds[54]: (Normal) ImportServer: Ignoring blacklisted Spotlight importer plugin:/Developer/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Library/Spotlight/SourceCode.mdimporter uuid:548A3091-3C5D-498A-A329-B532A6C896BB version:1801
Mar 25 08:10:06 --- last message repeated 7 times ---
Mar 25 08:10:06 MY_MAC_FQDN periodic-wrapper[481]: Running weekly periodic task.
Mar 25 08:11:42 MY_MAC_FQDN com.apple.SecurityServer[14]: Killing auth hosts
Mar 25 08:11:42 MY_MAC_FQDN com.apple.SecurityServer[14]: Session 100018 destroyed
Mar 25 08:13:04 MY_MAC_FQDN xpchelper[18813]: Info.plist does not contain an XPCService dictionary: /private/var/folders/zz/zyxvpxvq6csfxvn_n0000000000000/C/PKInstallSandboxManager/F6C0BA1F-2DFD-4DC2-B05F-35A23D991D09.activeSandbox/Root/System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Versions/A/XPCServices/SecurityAgent.xpc
Mar 25 08:13:05 MY_MAC_FQDN mds[54]: (Normal) ImportServer: Preparing for software update
Mar 25 08:13:46 MY_MAC_FQDN coreservicesd[33]: Posted system configuration change notification
Mar 25 08:15:04 MY_MAC_FQDN efilogin-helper[18831]: targetVolume: /
Mar 25 08:15:12 MY_MAC kernel[0]: hfs: mounted Recovery HD on device disk0s4
Mar 25 08:15:12 MY_MAC_FQDN mds[54]: (Normal) Volume: volume:0x7ff15b1a4000 ********** Bootstrapped Creating a default store:0 SpotLoc:(null) SpotVerLoc:(null) occlude:0 /Volumes/Recovery HD
Mar 25 08:15:13 MY_MAC_FQDN fseventsd[61]: Logging disabled completely for device:1: /Volumes/Recovery HD
Mar 25 08:15:14 MY_MAC kernel[0]: hfs: unmount initiated on Recovery HD on device disk0s4
Mar 25 08:15:21 MY_MAC_FQDN mds[54]: (Normal) ImportServer: Software update complete
Mar 25 08:15:27 MY_MAC_FQDN efilogin-helper[18888]: targetVolume: /
Mar 25 08:15:27 MY_MAC_FQDN com.apple.kextcache[18889]: / locked; waiting for lock.
Mar 25 08:15:32 MY_MAC_FQDN com.apple.kextcache[18890]: / locked; waiting for lock.
Mar 25 08:15:34 MY_MAC kernel[0]: hfs: mounted Recovery HD on device disk0s4
Mar 25 08:15:34 MY_MAC_FQDN mds[54]: (Normal) Volume: volume:0x7ff15b848000 ********** Bootstrapped Creating a default store:0 SpotLoc:(null) SpotVerLoc:(null) occlude:0 /Volumes/Recovery HD
Mar 25 08:15:34 MY_MAC_FQDN fseventsd[61]: Logging disabled completely for device:1: /Volumes/Recovery HD
Mar 25 08:15:35 MY_MAC kernel[0]: hfs: unmount initiated on Recovery HD on device disk0s4
Mar 25 08:15:35 MY_MAC_FQDN com.apple.kextcache[18889]: Lock acquired; proceeding.
Mar 25 08:15:35 MY_MAC_FQDN com.apple.kextd[12]: '/' updating, delaying reboot.
Mar 25 08:15:35 MY_MAC_FQDN com.apple.kextcache[18889]: /: helper partitions appear up to date.
Mar 25 08:15:35 MY_MAC_FQDN com.apple.kextcache[18890]: Lock acquired; proceeding.
Mar 25 08:15:35 MY_MAC_FQDN com.apple.kextd[12]: / is still busy, delaying reboot.
Mar 25 08:15:35 MY_MAC_FQDN com.apple.kextcache[18890]: /: helper partitions appear up to date.
Mar 25 08:15:36 MY_MAC_FQDN com.apple.kextd[12]:  up to date; unblocking reboot.
Mar 25 08:15:36 MY_MAC_FQDN reboot[18899]: rebooted by _atsserver
Mar 25 08:15:36 MY_MAC kernel[0]: Kext loading now disabled.
Mar 25 08:15:36 MY_MAC kernel[0]: Kext unloading now disabled.
Mar 25 08:15:36 MY_MAC kernel[0]: Kext autounloading now disabled.
Mar 25 08:15:36 MY_MAC kernel[0]: Kernel requests now disabled.
Mar 25 08:15:36 MY_MAC_FQDN reboot[18899]: SHUTDOWN_TIME: 1395731736 233985
Mar 25 08:15:36 MY_MAC_FQDN WindowServer[18760]: CGXGetConnectionProperty: Invalid connection 31491
Mar 25 08:33:02 localhost bootlog[0]: BOOT_TIME 1395732782 0
Mar 25 08:33:40 localhost syslogd[19]: Configuration Notice:
    ASL Module "com.apple.MessageTracer" claims selected messages.
    Those messages may not appear in standard system log files or in the ASL database.
Mar 25 08:33:40 localhost syslogd[19]: Configuration Notice:
    ASL Module "com.apple.appstore" claims selected messages.
    Those messages may not appear in standard system log files or in the ASL database.
Mar 25 08:33:40 localhost syslogd[19]: Configuration Notice:
    ASL Module "com.apple.authd" sharing output destination "/var/log/system.log" with ASL Module "com.apple.asl".
    Output parameters from ASL Module "com.apple.asl" override any specified in ASL Module "com.apple.authd".
Mar 25 08:33:40 localhost syslogd[19]: Configuration Notice:
    ASL Module "com.apple.authd" claims selected messages.
    Those messages may not appear in standard system log files or in the ASL database.
Mar 25 08:33:40 localhost syslogd[19]: Configuration Notice:
    ASL Module "com.apple.bookstore" claims selected messages.
    Those messages may not appear in standard system log files or in the ASL database.
Mar 25 08:33:40 localhost syslogd[19]: Configuration Notice:
    ASL Module "com.apple.eventmonitor" claims selected messages.
    Those messages may not appear in standard system log files or in the ASL database.
Mar 25 08:33:40 localhost syslogd[19]: Configuration Notice:
    ASL Module "com.apple.install" claims selected messages.
    Those messages may not appear in standard system log files or in the ASL database.
Mar 25 08:33:40 localhost syslogd[19]: Configuration Notice:
    ASL Module "com.apple.iokit.power" claims selected messages.
    Those messages may not appear in standard system log files or in the ASL database.
Mar 25 08:33:40 localhost syslogd[19]: Configuration Notice:
    ASL Module "com.apple.mail" claims selected messages.
    Those messages may not appear in standard system log files or in the ASL database.
Mar 25 08:33:40 localhost syslogd[19]: Configuration Notice:
    ASL Module "com.apple.performance" claims selected messages.
    Those messages may not appear in standard system log files or in the ASL database.
Mar 25 08:33:40 localhost syslogd[19]: Configuration Notice:
    ASL Module "com.apple.securityd" claims selected messages.
    Those messages may not appear in standard system log files or in the ASL database.
Mar 25 08:33:41 --- last message repeated 6 times ---
Mar 25 08:33:40 localhost kernel[0]: Longterm timer threshold: 1000 ms
Mar 25 08:33:40 localhost kernel[0]: PMAP: PCID enabled
Mar 25 08:33:40 localhost kernel[0]: Darwin Kernel Version 13.1.0: Thu Jan 16 19:40:37 PST 2014; root:xnu-2422.90.20~2/RELEASE_X86_64
Mar 25 08:33:40 localhost kernel[0]: vm_page_bootstrap: 869814 free pages and 170570 wired pages
Mar 25 08:33:40 localhost kernel[0]: kext submap [0xffffff7f807a6000 - 0xffffff8000000000], kernel text [0xffffff8000200000 - 0xffffff80007a6000]
Mar 25 08:33:40 localhost kernel[0]: zone leak detection enabled
Mar 25 08:33:40 localhost kernel[0]: "vm_compressor_mode" is 4
Mar 25 08:33:40 localhost kernel[0]: standard timeslicing quantum is 10000 us
Mar 25 08:33:40 localhost kernel[0]: standard background quantum is 2500 us
Mar 25 08:33:40 localhost kernel[0]: mig_table_max_displ = 74
Mar 25 08:33:40 localhost kernel[0]: AppleACPICPU: ProcessorId=1 LocalApicId=0 Enabled
Mar 25 08:33:40 localhost kernel[0]: AppleACPICPU: ProcessorId=2 LocalApicId=1 Enabled
Mar 25 08:33:40 localhost kernel[0]: AppleACPICPU: ProcessorId=3 LocalApicId=4 Enabled
Mar 25 08:33:40 localhost kernel[0]: AppleACPICPU: ProcessorId=4 LocalApicId=5 Enabled
Mar 25 08:33:40 localhost kernel[0]: AppleACPICPU: ProcessorId=5 LocalApicId=0 Disabled
Mar 25 08:33:40 localhost kernel[0]: AppleACPICPU: ProcessorId=6 LocalApicId=0 Disabled
Mar 25 08:33:40 localhost kernel[0]: AppleACPICPU: ProcessorId=7 LocalApicId=0 Disabled
Mar 25 08:33:40 localhost kernel[0]: AppleACPICPU: ProcessorId=8 LocalApicId=0 Disabled
Mar 25 08:33:40 localhost kernel[0]: calling mpo_policy_init for TMSafetyNet
Mar 25 08:33:40 localhost kernel[0]: Security policy loaded: Safety net for Time Machine (TMSafetyNet)
Mar 25 08:33:40 localhost kernel[0]: calling mpo_policy_init for Sandbox
Mar 25 08:33:40 localhost kernel[0]: Security policy loaded: Seatbelt sandbox policy (Sandbox)
Mar 25 08:33:40 localhost kernel[0]: calling mpo_policy_init for Quarantine
Mar 25 08:33:40 localhost kernel[0]: Security policy loaded: Quarantine policy (Quarantine)
Mar 25 08:33:40 localhost kernel[0]: Copyright (c) 1982, 1986, 1989, 1991, 1993
Mar 25 08:33:40 localhost kernel[0]: The Regents of the University of California. All rights reserved.
Mar 25 08:33:40 localhost kernel[0]: MAC Framework successfully initialized
Mar 25 08:33:40 localhost kernel[0]: using 16384 buffer headers and 10240 cluster IO buffer headers
Mar 25 08:33:40 localhost kernel[0]: AppleKeyStore starting (BUILT: Sep 19 2013 22:20:34)
Mar 25 08:33:40 localhost kernel[0]: IOAPIC: Version 0x20 Vectors 64:87
Mar 25 08:33:40 localhost kernel[0]: ACPI: sleep states S3 S4 S5
Mar 25 08:33:40 localhost kernel[0]: AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement: Turbo Ratios 0000
Mar 25 08:33:40 localhost kernel[0]: AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement: (built 19:46:50 Jan 16 2014) initialization complete
Mar 25 08:33:40 localhost kernel[0]: pci (build 20:00:24 Jan 16 2014), flags 0x63008, pfm64 (36 cpu) 0xf80000000, 0x80000000
Mar 25 08:33:40 localhost kernel[0]: [ PCI configuration begin ]
Mar 25 08:33:40 localhost kernel[0]: console relocated to 0xf80010000
Mar 25 08:33:40 localhost kernel[0]: [ PCI configuration end, bridges 7, devices 15 ]
Mar 25 08:33:40 localhost kernel[0]: [ PCI configuration begin ]
Mar 25 08:33:40 localhost kernel[0]: [ PCI configuration end, bridges 8, devices 21 ]
Mar 25 08:33:40 localhost kernel[0]: FireWire (OHCI) TI ID 823f built-in now active, GUID dc2b61fffecbdec8; max speed s800.
Mar 25 08:33:40 localhost kernel[0]: mcache: 4 CPU(s), 64 bytes CPU cache line size
Mar 25 08:33:40 localhost kernel[0]: mbinit: done [64 MB total pool size, (42/21) split]
Mar 25 08:33:40 localhost kernel[0]: Pthread support ABORTS when sync kernel primitives misused
Mar 25 08:33:40 localhost kernel[0]: rooting via boot-uuid from /chosen: 992FEDBA-6CDB-3089-990E-846BAEFE15E6
Mar 25 08:33:40 localhost kernel[0]: Waiting on <dict ID="0"><key>IOProviderClass</key><string ID="1">IOResources</string><key>IOResourceMatch</key><string ID="2">boot-uuid-media</string></dict>
Mar 25 08:33:40 localhost kernel[0]: com.apple.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib kmod start
Mar 25 08:33:40 localhost kernel[0]: com.apple.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless kmod start
Mar 25 08:33:40 localhost kernel[0]: com.apple.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib load succeeded
Mar 25 08:33:40 localhost kernel[0]: com.apple.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless load succeeded
Mar 25 08:33:40 localhost kernel[0]: AppleIntelCPUPowerManagementClient: ready
Mar 25 08:33:40 localhost kernel[0]: CoreStorage: fsck_cs has finished for group "50CF3474-AEED-440E-9F52-DC9FEBFB7DD8" with status 0x00
Mar 25 08:33:40 localhost kernel[0]: USBMSC Identifier (non-unique): 000000009833 0x5ac 0x8403 0x9833, 2
Mar 25 08:33:40 localhost kernel[0]: Got boot device = IOService:/AppleACPIPlatformExpert/PCI0@0/AppleACPIPCI/SATA@1F,2/AppleIntelPchSeriesAHCI/PRT0@0/IOAHCIDevice@0/AppleAHCIDiskDriver/IOAHCIBlockStorageDevice/IOBlockStorageDriver/ST3500418AS Media/IOGUIDPartitionScheme/MY_MAC_HD2@3/CoreStoragePhysical/MY_MAC_HD2/MY_MAC_HD2
Mar 25 08:33:40 localhost kernel[0]: BSD root: disk1, major 1, minor 6
Mar 25 08:33:40 localhost kernel[0]: hfs: mounted MY_MAC_HD2 on device root_device
Mar 25 08:33:40 localhost kernel[0]: ath_get_caps[4044] rx chainmask mismatch actual 3 sc_chainmak 0
Mar 25 08:33:40 localhost kernel[0]: 2.385897: ath_get_caps[4019] tx chainmask mismatch actual 3 sc_chainmak 0
Mar 25 08:33:40 localhost kernel[0]: 2.390288: Atheros: mac 128.2 phy 13.0 radio 12.0
Mar 25 08:33:40 localhost kernel[0]: 2.390298: Use hw queue 0 for WME_AC_BE traffic
Mar 25 08:33:40 localhost kernel[0]: 2.390305: Use hw queue 1 for WME_AC_BK traffic
Mar 25 08:33:40 localhost kernel[0]: 2.390311: Use hw queue 2 for WME_AC_VI traffic
Mar 25 08:33:40 localhost kernel[0]: 2.390317: Use hw queue 3 for WME_AC_VO traffic
Mar 25 08:33:40 localhost kernel[0]: 2.390324: Use hw queue 8 for CAB traffic
Mar 25 08:33:40 localhost kernel[0]: 2.390329: Use hw queue 9 for beacons
Mar 25 08:33:40 localhost kernel[0]: 2.390433: wlan_vap_create : enter. devhandle=0x8839e6b0, opmode=IEEE80211_M_STA, flags=0x1
Mar 25 08:33:40 localhost kernel[0]: 2.390482: wlan_vap_create : exit. devhandle=0x8839e6b0, opmode=IEEE80211_M_STA, flags=0x1.
Mar 25 08:33:40 localhost kernel[0]: 2.390525: ATH tunables:
Mar 25 08:33:40 localhost kernel[0]: 2.390529:   pullmode[1] txringsize[  256] txsendqsize[1024] reapmin[   32] reapcount[  128]
Mar 25 08:33:03 localhost com.apple.launchd[1]: *** launchd[1] has started up. ***
Mar 25 08:33:03 localhost com.apple.launchd[1]: *** Shutdown logging is enabled. ***
Mar 25 08:33:35 localhost com.apple.SecurityServer[14]: Session 100000 created
Mar 25 08:33:40 localhost distnoted[18]: # distnote server daemon  absolute time: 33.952924626   civil time: Tue Mar 25 08:33:35 2014   pid: 18 uid: 0  root: yes
Mar 25 08:33:41 localhost kernel[0]: IO80211Controller::dataLinkLayerAttachComplete():  adding AppleEFINVRAM notification
Mar 25 08:33:41 localhost kernel[0]: IO80211Interface::efiNVRAMPublished():  
Mar 25 08:33:42 localhost kernel[0]: IOBluetoothUSBDFU::probe
Mar 25 08:33:42 localhost kernel[0]: IOBluetoothUSBDFU::probe ProductID - 0x8215 FirmwareVersion - 0x0207
Mar 25 08:33:42 localhost kernel[0]: **** [IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport][start] -- completed -- result = TRUE -- 0x4c00 ****
Mar 25 08:33:42 localhost kernel[0]: **** [BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport][start] -- Completed -- 0x4c00 ****
Mar 25 08:33:42 localhost kernel[0]: SMC::smcReadKeyAction ERROR: smcReadData8 failed for key LsNM (kSMCKeyNotFound)
Mar 25 08:33:42 localhost kernel[0]: SMC::smcReadKeyAction ERROR LsNM kSMCKeyNotFound(0x84) fKeyHashTable=0x0
Mar 25 08:33:42 localhost kernel[0]: SMC::smcGetLightshowVers ERROR: smcReadKey LsNM failed (kSMCKeyNotFound)
Mar 25 08:33:42 localhost kernel[0]: SMC::smcPublishLightshowVersion ERROR: smcGetLightshowVers failed (kSMCKeyNotFound)
Mar 25 08:33:42 localhost kernel[0]: SMC::smcInitHelper ERROR: smcPublishLightshowVersion failed (kSMCKeyNotFound)
Mar 25 08:33:42 localhost kernel[0]: Previous Shutdown Cause: 5
Mar 25 08:33:42 localhost kernel[0]: SMC::smcInitHelper ERROR: MMIO regMap == NULL - fall back to old SMC mode
Mar 25 08:33:42 localhost kernel[0]: flow_divert_kctl_disconnect (0): disconnecting group 1
Mar 25 08:33:42 localhost com.apple.SecurityServer[14]: Entering service
Mar 25 08:33:42 localhost UserEventAgent[11]: Captive: CNPluginHandler en1: Inactive
Mar 25 08:33:42 localhost UserEventAgent[11]: Failed to copy info dictionary for bundle /System/Library/UserEventPlugins/alfUIplugin.plugin
Mar 25 08:33:42 MY_MAC.local configd[17]: setting hostname to "MY_MAC.local"
Mar 25 08:33:42 MY_MAC.local configd[17]: network changed.
Mar 25 08:33:42 MY_MAC kernel[0]: hfs: mounted MY_MAC_HD1 on device disk0s2
Mar 25 08:33:43 MY_MAC kernel[0]: init
Mar 25 08:33:43 MY_MAC kernel[0]: probe
Mar 25 08:33:43 MY_MAC kernel[0]: start
Mar 25 08:33:43 MY_MAC kernel[0]: DSMOS has arrived
Mar 25 08:33:43 MY_MAC kernel[0]: [IOBluetoothHCIController][staticBluetoothHCIControllerTransportShowsUp] -- Received Bluetooth Controller register service notification -- 0x4c00 
Mar 25 08:33:43 MY_MAC kernel[0]: [IOBluetoothHCIController][start] -- completed
Mar 25 08:33:43 MY_MAC kernel[0]: ** Device in slot: SLOT--1 **
Mar 25 08:33:43 MY_MAC kernel[0]: [IOBluetoothHCIController::setConfigState] calling registerService
Mar 25 08:33:43 MY_MAC kernel[0]: **** [IOBluetoothHCIController][protectedBluetoothHCIControllerTransportShowsUp] -- Connected to the transport successfully -- 0x2080 -- 0x8000 -- 0x4c00 ****
Mar 25 08:33:43 MY_MAC kernel[0]: hfs: mounted MY_MAC_HD3 on device disk0s5
Mar 25 08:33:45 MY_MAC.local hidd[72]: void __IOHIDPlugInLoadBundles(): Loaded 0 HID plugins
Mar 25 08:33:45 MY_MAC.local hidd[72]: Posting 'com.apple.iokit.hid.displayStatus' notifyState=1
Mar 25 08:33:45 MY_MAC kernel[0]: Ethernet [AppleBCM5701Ethernet]: Link up on en0, 1-Gigabit, Full-duplex, Symmetric flow-control, Debug [796d,0301,0de1,0300,c5e1,3c00]
Mar 25 08:33:45 MY_MAC.local aosnotifyd[92]: aosnotifyd has been launched
Mar 25 08:33:45 MY_MAC aosnotifyd[92]: assertion failed: 13C64: liblaunch.dylib + 25164 [38D1AB2C-A476-385F-8EA8-7AB604CA1F89]: 0x25
Mar 25 08:33:46 MY_MAC.local awacsd[82]: Starting awacsd connectivity_executables-97 (Aug 24 2013 23:49:23)
Mar 25 08:33:46 MY_MAC kernel[0]: AppleBCM5701Ethernet [en0]:       44     e258 receivePackets - got vlan packet
Mar 25 08:33:46 MY_MAC.local awacsd[82]: InnerStore CopyAllZones: no info in Dynamic Store
Mar 25 08:33:47 MY_MAC.local airportd[85]: airportdProcessDLILEvent: en1 attached (down)
Mar 25 08:33:47 MY_MAC kernel[0]: AtherosNewma40P2PInterface::init name <p2p0> role 1
Mar 25 08:33:47 MY_MAC kernel[0]: AtherosNewma40P2PInterface::init() <p2p> role 1
Mar 25 08:33:47 MY_MAC kernel[0]: AirPort: Link Down on en1. Reason 8 (Disassociated because station leaving).
Mar 25 08:33:47 MY_MAC kernel[0]: 45.595754: setDISASSOC from ATH_INTERFACE_CLASS disconnectVap
Mar 25 08:33:47 MY_MAC kernel[0]: 45.595777: switchVap from 1 to 1 
Mar 25 08:33:47 MY_MAC.local airportd[85]: _handleLinkEvent: WiFi is not powered. Resetting state variables.
Mar 25 08:33:50 MY_MAC.local configd[17]: network changed: v4(en0+:MY_MAC_IP) DNS+ Proxy+ SMB
Mar 25 08:33:51 MY_MAC.local digest-service[95]: label: default
Mar 25 08:33:51 MY_MAC.local digest-service[95]:        dbname: od:/Local/Default
Mar 25 08:33:51 MY_MAC.local digest-service[95]:        mkey_file: /var/db/krb5kdc/m-key
Mar 25 08:33:51 MY_MAC.local digest-service[95]:        acl_file: /var/db/krb5kdc/kadmind.acl
Mar 25 08:33:52 MY_MAC kernel[0]: VM Swap Subsystem is ON
Mar 25 08:33:52 MY_MAC kernel[0]: **** [IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport][SuspendDevice] -- Suspend -- suspendDeviceCallResult = 0x0000 (kIOReturnSuccess) -- 0x4c00 ****
Mar 25 08:33:52 MY_MAC.local systemkeychain[98]: done file: /var/run/systemkeychaincheck.done
Mar 25 08:33:52 MY_MAC.local digest-service[95]: digest-request: uid=0
Mar 25 08:33:52 MY_MAC.local digest-service[95]: digest-request: netr probe 0
Mar 25 08:33:52 MY_MAC.local digest-service[95]: digest-request: init request
Mar 25 08:33:52 MY_MAC.local digest-service[95]: digest-request: init return domain: BUILTIN server: DIRAC indomain was: <NULL>
```

from this time the loginwindow is displayed and the system looks

like running

Comment: According to the very short console log, it tried to reboot but run in to a waiting loop (do you have a external monitor hooked up?). It is working now is it ?

Comment: → Buscar: no external monitor. This iMac is a pretty freshly installed Mavericks 10.9.0 and I "think" highly clean and secured. I'll look at my `/var/log/system.log` if there is any related information I might include in my OQ.

Comment: Console is a good place to look, so what it did after the problem report at Mar 25 08:33:02 localhost bootlog[0]: BOOT_TIME 1395732782 0

Comment: → Buscar: as explained in the OQ, the console was a total black screen. I was n°1 witness :[.

Comment: Quick question: is it at all possible that you installed the updates when proposed to right after asking your mac to shutdown?

Comment: → Édouard: good hypothesis. But no, I'm sure I didn't fire a shutdown.